# css changes doesnt reflect on my project on localhost

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, flask

I am doing a Blog Post project in Flask. While I am designing my project through CSS it seems to not reflect while running on the localhost. And while executing the files it shows:-

- Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: on
- Restarting with windowsapi reloader
- Debugger is active!
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  What does this line "Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)" mean?
  And sometimes when I execute my file the winowsapi reloader keeps on loading.
  Can anyone suggest ways to overcome these?

Comment: is the HTML and CSS files in the templates folder? is CSS file linked with HTML file?

Comment: Yes, the html file is in the templates folder and the css file is in the statics folder. And I have linked them by  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css">

Comment: better use absolute path - starting with `/` - `/static/main.css`. If you will use relative path `static/main.css` on ie. page `/index/` then it will search `/index/static/main.css`

Comment: But it's still not changing

Comment: sometimes web browser may keep old version in cache and you may need turn off cache in web browser, or clear it, or try `Ctrl+F5` to reload without using cache. Or you can add random argument with `?` - ie, `/static/main.css?2020.08.11.08:45` and it will treat it as new url.

Comment: in `DevTool` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` in tab `Network` you can check if it has no problem to load this file.

Comment: Yeah, it did work ..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes web browser may keep old version in cache and you may need turn off cache in web browser, or clear it, or try `Ctrl+F5` to reload without using cache.

Or you can add random argument with `?` to url - ie, `/static/main.css?2020.08.11.08:45` and web browser will treat it as new url so it will read it from server.

In `DevTool` in `Firefox/Chrome` in tab `Network` you can check if it has no problem to load this file. It should show also if it was readed from cache.